# Включение/выключение фильтра внутри метода по атрибуту

Tags: c#, атрибуты

У меня есть CRUD сервис в котором есть довольно много одинакового кода. Он наследуется от абстрактного класса (в нем уже реализуется всё что надо для crud). Почти все методы (тут показал только на примере `Update`) имеют одинаковую структуру. Как сделать атрибут который бы автоматически включал/выключал мультитенантность для администратора (т.е с `Id = null`)?

```
class ContractCrudService : CrudAppService<ContractStatus, ContractStatusDto, Guid, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, CreateUpdateContractStatusDto>
{
   public override async Task<ContractDto> UpdateAsync(Guid id, CreateUpdateContractDto dto)
   {
       if(CurrentTenant.Id == null)
       {
           using (DataFilter.Disable<IMultiTenant>())
           {
               return await base.UpdateAsync(id, dto);
           }
       }
       return await base.UpdateAsync(id, dto);
   }
}
```

Я попытался сам написать подобный атрибут, но попытка закончилась после переопределения `Match` т.к нет даже мыслей как подобное сделать

Comment: `Guid` структура, он не может быть `null`.

Comment: @aepot `Nullable<Guid>` используется. `CurrentTenant` там вообще где-то создается со своими свойствами и у него всегда `Nullable<Guid>`. Он не связан с типами которые я передаю в `CrudAppService`

Comment: Стеклянный шар разбился вчера, простите :) Зачем именно аттрибут? Этот метод вообще работает как надо или нет?

Comment: @aepot можно не атрибут, просто рефакторингом занялся. Пометить атрибутом переопределенный метод проще, чем трогать его тело и добавлять всякие `if`, `using` итп.. т.к у меня сейчас минимум 2 сервиса похожих и еще фиг знает сколько появится) поэтому легче сделать атрибут для того чтобы там само включалось если `Id == null`. Методы работают как надо

Comment: То что у вас 2 раза `await base.UpdateAsync` подряд в методе вызывается - это норма?

Comment: @aepot да, это норм. Если условия срабатывает значит мы под админ хостом, а значит надо выключать мультитенант и соответственно иметь доступ ко всем записям таблицы. Если мультитенант включен, то значит мы под дефолтным юзером, и соответственно не имеем доступ ко всей таблице в бд, а только к "своим" записям

Comment: Это понятно, а метод зачем дважды подряд вызывать с одними и теми же аргументами?? В ответе посмотрите, я внес изменения в логику, я точно ничего не починил?

Comment: @aepot затем, что забыл добавить `return` в блоке `using` :)

Comment: Ну вот, теперь моя и ваша логика совпадает, пробуйте.

Comment: А почему не сделать это в Global query filter? Делаем, как в документации: [Multi-tenancy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy#an-example-solution-single-database) и в фильтр дописываем `.HasQueryFilter(mt => mt.Tenant == _tenant || _tenant == "admin")`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, я завтра посмотрю!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, это неплохой способ, но к сожалению у меня нет доступа ко внешнему Dbcontext чтобы там добавить эту строчку. Мой DbContext наследуется от кастомного (я юзаю фреймворк)

Comment: @Aarnihauta - ну вот в своём DbContext и переопределите (override) метод `OnModelCreating`, где и добавьте `HasQueryFilter`. | Но я не настаиваю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написать метод-обертку можно

```
private async Task<T> TryDisableMultiTenantAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func) 
{
    if (CurrentTenant.Id is null)
    {
        using (DataFilter.Disable<IMultiTenant>())
        {
            return await func();
        }
    }
    return await func();
}
```

При желании, можно его в базоывй класс утащить.

```
public override Task<ContractDto> UpdateAsync(Guid id, CreateUpdateContractDto dto)
{
    return TryDisableMultiTenantAsync(() => base.UpdateAsync(id, dto));
}
```

---

Можно даже немного оптимизировать

```
private Task<T> TryDisableMultiTenantAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func) 
{
    async Task<T> DisableMultiTenantAsync() 
    {
        using (DataFilter.Disable<IMultiTenant>())
        {
            return await func();
        }
    }
    return CurrentTenant.Id is null ? DisableMultiTenantAsync() : func();
}
```

Здесь я выбросил асинхронную машину состояний, если `Id != null`